# Typescript type declaration of API result

Tags: typescript

So i've been trying to parse data from an api with typescript but cant get a grasp on how to declare the result type from the api. the request response can look something like:

```
{
       "Schema": [
          {
            "Name": "Timestamp",
            "Type": "String"
          },
          {
            "Name": "DeviceName",
            "Type": "String"
          },
          {
            "Name": "LoggedOnUsers",
            "Type": "String"
          }
        ],
        "Results": [
          {
            "Timestamp": "2021-01-19T17:57:18.0007177Z",
            "DeviceName": "internal\bobscomputer",
            "LoggedOnUsers": "Bob"
          },
          {
            "Timestamp": "2021-01-18T05:21:43.0081833Z",
            "DeviceName": "internal\Foo",
            "LoggedOnUsers": "Foo"
          },
        ]
}
```

i made a interface for the schema

```
export interface Schema {
        Name:string;
        Type:string | number;
}
```

the exact result of Schema will be based on the query which will vary from time to time. In the example i requested timestamp,devicename,loggedonusers. But next time i might want to add userid:number to the query which will then result in a slightly different schema and result.

so the question is how can i declare a apiResponse interface that will fit when i'm unknowing of the result?

```
export interface apiResponse {
    Schema : Schema[];
    Results:*???*;
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but maybe you're looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)?

Comment: Add all the possible keys in Schema and Results. There would be a limit to the names of the keys in each type.